# Backspace doesn't work in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I keep getting a very annoying problem in Visual Studio.  When I try to delete some text by pressing backspace it doesn't work.  Why is this?  What is going on?  Sometimes I have to close and open Visual Studio to make this problem go away but I just tried that right now and it didn't work.  Backspace works in Notepad in case you are wondering.

Comment: Are you using any vs add-ons?

Comment: Resharper - but I've disabled it.

Comment: Problem while installing software. Reinstall it may fix the problem

Comment: I installed Visual Studio a long while ago and this problem only started recently.

Comment: You maybe changed an option or something. the best way is reinstall it

Comment: I have no add ons, nothing special other than the stock VS 2013.  This has happened to me (very rarely) on a few occasions... but when it does it is mighty annoying!  Pressing Alt + Enter as suggested resolves.  Previous solution was to restart Visual Studio (less ideal, obviously).

Comment: Can also happen inside Parallels [on a Mac] - in my case arrow keys also do not work

Comment: This issue has been reported to Microsoft > 10 times in the past five years alone. I added a summary bug report which also links to this question. Hopefully it will finally get some attention other than "Closed - Not enough info" https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Backspace-etc-sometimes-stop-working/10543156

Comment: Nothing below worked - I had to switch to using VS Preview to fix this. No idea what caused it - perhaps a reinstall might work too (restart / reboot didn't either).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This seems to happen to me when I open a solution and there are files already open. I used to close the files, then close and re-open the solution to fix it, but now I just hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Here is the [blog where I found this trick](http://jvides.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/backspace-and-arrow-keys-stop-working/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11828/discussion-between-sachin-kainth-and-romil)

Comment: though backspace works for me , select and delete doesnt work for me. any idea why?

Answer (score 82):

In Visual Studio go to:

```
Tools 
Options
Environment
Keyboard
```

1. Find "Edit.DeleteBackwards" command.
2. In "Use new shortcut in:" dropdown select "Text Editor".
3. In "Press shortcut keys:" click backspace so it would show "Bkspce"
4. Click "OK".

Backspace should start working for you again.

Comment: I had this same problem happen but I am really curious how it happened. Did I maybe hit some random shortcut that changes the mapping...??

Comment: Thanks, seems using `default` in “Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme” in the keyboard setting UI will cause this issue, but if changed to `Visual C# 2005`, it worked.

Answer (score 51):

I solved this issue resetting keyboard mapping scheme.

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Reset.

Answer (score 16):

A quick fix for me is to simply open any menu from the menu bar. Once the menu is closed the non-character keys start to work again.

Comment: This worked for me in VS Code as well! Debugging a Python program in VS Code v1.64.2

Comment: WORKED! Version 17.8.6

Answer (score 11):

Except for the above methods.

You should also check the shortcut key settings:

File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> 'Then check the item: deleteLeft'.

[image]

Comment: though backspace works for me , select and delete doesnt work for me. any idea why?

Comment: This is helpful for *Visual Studio Code* however, the question is for *Visual Studio*.

Answer (score 8):

I get this from time to time in VS2010 as well and simply just **using the mouse to change tabs/files** seems to always fix it now. Nothing more.

Comment: To add to this - I think when I've encountered this it's been because VS has somehow lost track of the "active tab". It thinks some other tab is active so it's doing your edits on that other tab/file. Very weird issue.

Comment: though backspace works for me , select and delete doesnt work for me. any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

This method is working at 100%.
Go to "File-> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts" and search for deleteLeft and add keybinding "Backspace".

Comment: VSCode solution - verified

Answer (score 4):

Odd that this is still an issue even in VS 2019. Both the backspace and delete keys didn't work. Quick fix, I just ran the project and it seemed to give it the kick it needed.

Answer (score 3):

All I did was exit visual studio and restart it.None of the above options worked for me.

Comment: This happens almost every time I install a nuget package or load\reload an existing project. alt + enter sometimes works, otherwise this is the only other way to fix it.

Comment: This works for me. For 15 minutes. And then I have to restart again...

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was the "When" Condition in "File-> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts".

I removed "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly" and it works now as expected.
I'm looking forward to the side effects ;).

Answer (score 3):

Just had this exact issue (along with 'Enter', 'Ctrl+X', 'Ctrl+C', 'Ctrl+V', 'Ctrl+Z' keyboard mappings seemingly doing nothing) in the latest VS preview version below:

*Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.2.0 Preview 6.0*

The fix for me was to move to another tab (I had multiple open) use the backspace key which worked fine, then move back to the original tab with which it wasn't working, save the file (as it had outstanding changes) and then I found backspace and all other shortcuts then worked!

I can only think that VS got in a locked (to keyboard mappings) state for that particular tab.

A few notes on this:

- I knew it wasn't a keyboard issue as I was able to use those
  keys/mappings fine in other apps.
- I found closing and reopening VS didn't work.
- Also resetting the keyboard mappings (through Options menu as others have described) didn't work.
- I had multiple tabs open.
- Resharper was disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting your Visual Studio Settings

[image]

Go to :

```
All Program > Visual Studio 20xx > Visual Studio Tools
```

Run **Developer Command Prompt for VS20xx** as Administrator and this command:

`devenv.exe /resetsettings`

Answer (score 2):

A quick work-around for me is locking the pc (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and logging in again.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset keyboard mapping scheme like this

**Options** => **Environment** => **Keyboard** then select **(Default)** in the comboBox and click **Reset** button and then **Ok** button to confirm

[image]
[Visual studio 2019 : Keyboard mapping sheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DufWB.jpg)

Tested in Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 1):

This problem happened for me when I used a different version of resharper at home and then took that project to my employment.  Backspace works for me now after I deleted the bin and obj and resharper directories.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem after I install Vim, uninstall Vim Backspace works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When this issue has happened to me, I've found that hitting delete or backspace is unresponsive only within a portion of my code.  This portion happened to be some code that I've pasted in from the internet somewhere.

To fix this issue, I cut out the recently pasted problematic code and then pasted it into a text editor like Notepad++. Then copying and pasting that same code out of the text editor and back into Visual Studio fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio Community 2019 (16.4.3)

I just searched this issue because I could click in my document, type, et cetera, but I could not use backspace, delete, ctrl+z, or the arrow keys.

Opening the "File" menu, I noticed the Save option referred to a different file. I checked that file and found that all of the keys that seemed not to work were actually editing that other file.

Switching between the file in half-focus and the file I intended to edit worked and, luckily, undo was able to fix the file I unknowingly butchered.

If you wound up here, check your "File" menu to make sure the correct file is referenced, since the fix is quick and easy to try.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen in one instance of Visual Studio 2022, caused by the debug settings editor window being open in another instance of Visual Studio 2022 in the background where I couldn't see it.

Closing that window resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

go settings > keyboard shortcuts

then you will see this kind of interface there type "deleteleft" in my case that has been assigned to shift + backspace you can edit that one with selecting edit icon and pressing the key you need. check this image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats visual code not visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Had Vim extension installed without my consent and had to press I to get to edit mode

Answer (score -2):

I've had this issue for a long time. I'm not sure what causes it, but **Alt + Enter** works.
The extensions that I'm running include AnkhSVN, MySQL Tools, and Productivity Power Tools.